# "unsized object" error trying to remove files from a directory

Tags: object, ironpython

I'm trying to remove files that have an extension as .pcp from a directory.
If I list the directory I get:

```
>>> for i in os.listdir(folder):
...     if i.endswith(".pcp"):
...         print(i)
...
1.pcp
2.pcp
3.pcp
4.pcp
5.pcp
6.pcp
7.pcp
8.pcp
9.pcp
10.pcp
```

When if I run:

```
>>> for i in os.listdir(folder):
...     if i.endswith(".pcp"):
...         os.remove(os.path.join(dir, i))
...
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\ntpath.py", line 96, in join
TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

Please can you point out what mistake I'm doing? Help greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you made a typo when calling

```
os.remove(os.path.join(dir, i))
```

You don't get a NameError because dir is a builtin function.

---

Instead, you may want to call the line below :

```
os.remove(os.path.join(folder, i))
```

---

You can also use the `glob` module:

```
import glob
files = glob.glob(os.path.join(folder,'*.pcp'))
for f in files:
    os.remove(f)
```

Comment: Thank you! ... I overlooked the "dir" function/method. I tried your glob solution and works. Thanks again.